# How to print ArrayList into rows and columns?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an arraylist of 52 playing cards. I want to print them out [into 4 rows and 13 columns like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWMWD.png)
Right now, I only know how to print them all out in a straight line like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0z64.png).

This is how I construct my arraylist:

```
    private static void deckOfCards(ArrayList<PlayingCard> cardList)
    {           
        for(SuitEnum s : SuitEnum.values())
        {       
            for(RankEnum r: RankEnum.values())
            {
                cardList.add(new PlayingCard(s, r));
            }
        }           
    }
```

My current method to display the all the playing cards:

```
    private static void displayCards(ArrayList<PlayingCard> cardList)
    {
        for(PlayingCard p : cardList)
        {
            System.out.print(p);
        }   
    }
```

How do I print the cards nicely into 4 rows and 13 columns? Thanks.

Comment: Since you know the exact number of cards in a deck and number of cards  for a suit (which is also unlikely to change), why not use two regular nested for-loops to print your deck?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an index to only print 13 cards before each newline, and separate each card by a space character, like so:

```
private static void displayCards(ArrayList<PlayingCard> cardList)
{
    int idx = 0;
    for(PlayingCard p : cardList)
    {
        System.out.print(p+" ");
        if(idx++ == 13)
        {
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

This will work perfectly fine provided that you only have 52 cards each time and that they are already in the right order. As per your screenshots, this does appear to be the case. Alternatively, you can do something like the following (not using a for-each), provided the same conditions hold:

```
private static void displayCards(ArrayList<PlayingCard> cardList)
{
    for(int row = 0; row < 4; row++)
    {
        for(int col = 0; col < 13; col++)
        {
            System.out.print((col == 0 ? "" : " ") + cardList.get(row*13+col));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple way to output a fixed list with 13 columns and 4 rows, or multiples of 13 length list:

```
private static void displayCards(ArrayList<PlayingCard> cardList)
    {
        int counter=0;
          for(PlayingCard p : cardList)
        {
            System.out.print(p);
            counter++;
           if(counter%13==0){
               System.out.println();
           }
        }
    }
```